# How to post XML file to WPF WebBrowser Control locally?

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, webbrowser-control

I want to post XML file to WPF Browser Control locally.

I mean don't directly feed this XML file to  WPF Browser Control but read it and post it like byte[] array.

I guess to use NavigateToStream method for it...

I tried this but no success :(   Browser doesn't show any data at all.

```
byte[] attachment = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\CustomerData.xml");
MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream(attachment);
XMLBrowser.NavigateToStream((Stream)mStream);
```

Which is the best way to implement it in C#?

Comment: The question is _really_ hard to understand (even in quirks mode). What exactly are you trying to achieve (the problem, like "post a file to a server with HTTP Post", not the I-think-that's-the-solution,-now-how-can-I-do-this you may have come up with), what have you tried so far and what are you having problems with?

Comment: Hi! I want to use NavigateToStream method of WPF WebBrowser to show up XML data.

Answer (score 1):

The ideal solution what I need I found here "A Simple WPF XML Document Viewer Control" http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/71069/A-Simple-WPF-XML-Document-Viewer-Control